# Compare two Strings with Hashmap<String, List<String>>

Tags: java

I'm experimenting with a small usermanagement-system.
I have stored all data with this code:

```
public static HashMap<String, List<String>> loginData = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

The key is a username and the values (in the List) are password, first name, last name, id.

How can I check that entered username and password comply with the data in my HashMap?

This is how I checked the username:

```
if (loginData.containsKey(loginname) == true){
```

Comment: Instead of a list it might make it a little cleaner to use an Object such as UserData which could hold password, firstname, lastname etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the list like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> curData : loginData.entrySet()) {
    String username = curData.getKey();
    List<String> listLoginData = curData.getValue();

    String password = listLoginData.get(0);
    String first_name = listLoginData.get(1);
    ....
}
```

My advice for you is using a list of object, and create a class with this parameters, like this

```
public class LoginData {
    private String password;
    private String firstName;


    public LoginData(String password, String firstName){
       this.password = password;
       this.first_name =  firstName;
    }

  public String getPassword(){
    return password;
  }
  public String getFirstName(){
    return firstName;
  }
}
```

And then, use something like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<LoginData>> curData : loginData.entrySet()) {
    String username = curData.getKey();
    LoginData loginDataObject = curData.getValue();

    String password = loginDataObject.getPassword();
    String first_name = loginDataObject.getFirstName();
    ....
}
```

Comment: Can you change the post, and put this with "correct answer",please?

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain values connected with specific key in `HashMap` with

```
List<String> values = loginData.get(loginname);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    boolean validateLogin(String username, String password) {
      List<String> userDetails = loginData.get(username);
      return userDetails != null &&                
           userDetails.size() == 4 &&
           password.equals(userDetails.get(0));
    }
```